# jQuery Scrolling Script - why isnt it working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/7ypyL/1/

As you can see, the little box that comes first works fine and the jQuery works. However, I want the second scroll bar to look like the other one. You'll notice that both scrollable areas go under the same DIV id, but the second one isn't working.

I'm trying to implement it here: http://ewsprojects.com/~lyons/new.php (click on a thumbnail and then a tag)

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a class in stead of an id, double ids are not a good practice and in this case that's what goes wrong (document.findElementById() only finds the first one).

Improved jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ypyL/9/

Comment: It definitely works in JSfiddle, but when I try to implement the same on my site (see link in original post) it still doesn't work. Maybe it has something to do with this being included as part of a PHP foreach for all the tags?

Comment: Not really, you seem to be loading that part of the page through an ajax-call (android-vpn.jpg for the first item), and because that part of the HTML didn't exist when you called lionbars, it won't have them. You'll have to call lionbars over the new HTML again.